# How can I get the information which app is foreground in iOS?

Tags: ios, view, foreground

Can I get the information about which apps are on foreground, so that  controlling the  screen and get  interaction from user.

I can do it on Android and I want to do it also in iOS.

This is for making an app that monitoring the usages of apps, not for the CPU usage.

Please tell me how could I manage this ?

Answer (score 0):

On jailbroken devices, a quite straighforward solution is to use Ryan Petrich's [AppList library.](https://github.com/rpetrich/AppList)

I'm not sure if this is easy on a stock device, but you might get somewhere using the Mach/XNU API for retrieving process info and searching for a suspected app executable path/name.